# How to access the phone's screen like "Chromecast APP"?(Mirroring)

Tags: android, chromecast, wifi-direct, mirroring

I want make mirroring without WiFi-direct.

- like chromecast mirroring function.
- Chromecast application can    access screen without
  rooting&wifi-direct.

I found "capture_video_output" permission at API 19, but I can`t found any API.
So, I decompiled chromecast, but it hasn't "capture_video_output" permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Is it right way for mirroring?(wifi-display)

How can I make mirroring application?
Or where can I get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Presentation APIs to mirror a view within your app (can be a virtual view) to a chromecast device if mirroring is happening. Otherwise, there is no API for you to mirror phone's screen to a chromecast device.